# sqlite datetime format: which one is better?

Tags: java, c#, android, sqlite

I'm creating a sqlite database from my c# project which will be used in my android application later on.

I have a **CreateDate** column in my sqlite database which I will need to get records ordered by this column later in my android application. Now my question is that is it better to save the date time as TEXT with **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS** format or I just convert all my dates into **miliseconds** and order them easily later since it's just a number?

Which one is easier to be ordered later in mobile application? or maybe my approaches are wrong so please feel free to shoot me with some best practices for this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Corak I know that but sqlite handles date as text as far as I know. So you think handling it by converting the date to unix timestamp is better approach?

Comment: Sorry, just saw that sqlite handles datetime information in a weird way. Not sure how this is "really" stored behind the curtains, but sorting by number is (almost?) always a lot faster than sorting by string.

Comment: @Corak Yea I also think so, because I can sort it by SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY date(dateColumn) DESC but I think storing as long miliseconds would make it quiet easier, also for converting it back to datetime it will be easier I suppose. Don't you think so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well **unix timestamp** looks simple and easier but i wont recommend you this.
 [Check out this gif.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Year_2038_problem.gif)
**What happens on January 19, 2038?**
On this date the Unix Time Stamp will cease to work due to a 32-bit overflow. Before this moment millions of applications will need to either adopt a new convention for time stamps or be migrated to 64-bit systems which will buy the time stamp a "bit" more time.

Therefore i would suggest you to stick with **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS** format as it is both C# and Android compatible(or parseable i should say) and neither would string overflow in near future ;)

Good Luck.

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense, and  about the ordering it by that formatted date text, is it gonna cause any problem by any chance? What do you think about miliseconds or seconds?

Comment: @arashmoeen nope it will order correctly, descending order will give you the latest on the top....
Milliseconds arent gonna make much difference

Comment: Unix timestamps use seconds; Java timestamps use milliseconds, with which the overflow would have already happened if anybody used 32-bit integers, which nobody does.

Comment: @Salmaan Ok then, that should do it. thanks for your help mate.